How to add scientific names of birds to manuscript?
A common task in scientific writing is adding scientific names after the English name. This is a highly laborious task with a lot of room for error. It seems remarkable that nobody has come up with software to do the task. Or am I missing something? What methods do people use to efficiently and accurately add scientific names to manuscripts?
Here are some that I need to follow, although these vary among journals:

add the scientific name after the first mention of each English name in the main text
scientific names need to be in italics
once a genus (the first of the two scientific names) has been mentioned in the main text, the genus needs use the first initial
any mention of the English name in the bodies of tables always needs full scientific name adding
in figure captions, each English name needs scientific adding, but as with the main text, once a scientific has been used it does not need repeating and once a genus has been mentioned then only the first initial should be be used


Perhaps related: Automatic species names in latex

I’m curious, is this really considered ‘a highly laborious task’ for a researcher?
